# How do I copy a nested JSON list for a question?

Tags: r, nested-lists, purrr

I'm looking for help on a JSON list that I extracted using `jsonlite`.  The list has additional lists embedded within it, along with `df` embedded as well.  How can I most easily copy the content to SO to post for help?  Also, some of the data is sensitive, so I'm hoping there is a solution that can randomize the values, or allow me to easily manipulate them.

Comment: Don't share your data. Share a minimal fake replica of it which mimics the aspect you need help with.

Comment: I need help with most of the extraction of the nested list.  How would I copy it from RStudio in list format?

Comment: Your question says "a JSON list that I extracted using jsonlite" and now you are saying "I need help with most of the extraction of the nested list". These are contradicting. Let's start here: Dicts are not lists or nested lists. The expression "JSON list" is misleading, must be dict. Please edit your question with the right terminology and try to give an example of what you are trying to describe -- right now there is no way to understand.

Answer (score -1):

As you know, you can parse JSON data using `fromJSON()`

To access items within the parsed JSON data, you use the same method you would to access other things, that is, R's accessor function `$`, not forgetting that it can take you multiple layers deep e.g. `your_data$details$result$locationHierarchy$city`

Here are some tips to help you easily copy your data as text (e.g. to copy to a SO question)

Let's take some data

```
some_data <- iris[1, ]
some_data

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

You can convert any R object (e.g. a dataframe, vector, element etc) into JSON format using `toJSON()`

```
some_data_as_JSON <- toJSON(some_data)
some_data_as_JSON

# [{"Sepal.Length":5.1,"Sepal.Width":3.5,"Petal.Length":1.4,"Petal.Width":0.2,"Species":"setosa"}]
```

In the example above, if you try to copy/paste the JSON data returned to the R console, it will error, since the special characters are not escaped properly. However, there is an easy way around this using `dput()`

```
dput(some_data_as_JSON)

# structure("[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"}]", class = "json")
```

Now you **can** copy/paste that output and assign it as an R object! (so this is perfect for a SO question)

When anonomysing data, you could try using randomizing function like `runif()` to generate random data for numeric data types. For characters, you could try `gsub()` one character for another randomly (this would not be strong anonymisation but could be okay depending on what you're trying to do). Or you could generate random strings using

```
library(stringi)
stri_rand_strings(3, 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")
```

One last tip: SO tends to prefer small reproducable examples (as opposed to large ones), so perhaps the best thing to do would be to take a small subset of your data to copy on to SO, or perhaps even make an entirely new object (a small one should be enough)